# Why can't I see the Pokémon in a live camera mode?

Tags: pokemon-go

I see the AR switch in the upper right corner and I have toggled it back and forth but I can not see the Pokémon in my surroundings. I either see them on a white screen or on a digital forest background. How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe the App doesn't have permission to your account. You have to change that in your phone's settings.

Comment: I know that when I started pokemon go it asked if the app could record and take vides when it wanted to. I denied that request. If that is the cause how can I change it?

Comment: In Android you can either go in settings-->notifcations or into the app details. you have to search a bit as I can't lookup. In iOS its settings-->Pokemon GO

Comment: Thank you h0ch5tr4355! I went into my phone settings and fixed it!

Answer (score 7):

You said in your comments that when you were asked if Pokémon Go could access your camera, you said no. This means that the game does not have permission to turn on your camera, so you won't see anything.

Granting Pokémon Go the permission to access your camera should fix this problem.

In iOS:

1. Open the Settings app
2. Scroll down to your list of apps and choose "Pokémon Go"
3. Switch "Camera" from off to on

In Android:

1. Open the Settings app
2. Tap “Apps” under the Device heading
3. Select Pokémon Go
4. Tap "Permissions"
5. Switch "Camera" from off to on

If you want to save any pictures you take, you should also turn on the ability to access photos.

Comment: Another issue can be that they are too far away from the pokemon- you do have to get closer with AR on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AR mode if your phone doesn't have a gyroscope sensor. On Android download a phone sensor app so you can check if you have a gyroscope.